# The closed form of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{n}} d x$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, contour-integration

We are going to deal with the integral
$$
I_{n}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)^{n}} d x
$$
by differentiation on its related integral
$$
J(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^{2}+a} d x,
$$

where $a>0$

Using contour integration along anti-clockwise direction of the path
$$\gamma=\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2} \textrm{ where }  \gamma_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R)  \textrm{ and } \gamma_{2}(t)=R e^{i t}  (0<t<\pi) $$
$$
\begin{aligned}
J(a) &=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^{2}+a} d x \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re} \int_{\gamma} \frac{e^{i z}}{z^{2}+a} d z \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re}\left[2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{e^{i z}}{z^{2}+a}, \sqrt{a} i\right)\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re}\left[2 \pi i \frac{e^{i(\sqrt{a} i)}}{2 \cdot \sqrt{a} i}\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re}\left[\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}} e^{-\sqrt{a}}\right] \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{a}} e^{-\sqrt{a}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $a$ by $(n-1)$ times yields

$$
\left.I_{n}=\frac{\pi}{(n-1)!}J^{(n-1)}(1)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1} \pi}{2(n-1) !} \frac{d^{n-1}}{d a^{n-1}}\left(\frac{e^{-\sqrt{a}}}{\sqrt{a}}\right)\right|_{a=1}
$$

Noting that

$$
\frac{d}{d a}\left(e^{-\sqrt{a}}\right)=-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{a}} e^{-\sqrt{a}},
$$

we have $$
I_{n}=\left.\frac{(-1)^{n} \pi}{(n-1) !} \cdot \frac{d^{n}}{d a^{n}}\left(e^{-\sqrt{a}}\right)\right|_{a=1}
$$
By the formula, we can find
$$
I_{1}=\frac{\pi}{2e};I_{2}=\frac{\pi}{2 e};
I_{3}=\frac{7 \pi}{16 e} ;
I_{4}=\frac{37 \pi}{96e} ;
I_{5}=\frac{133 \pi}{384 e};\cdots\ 
I_{10}=\frac{12994393 \pi}{53084160 e}
$$

***Suggestions on how to deal with the last derivative is highly appreciated.***

Comment: What is your question...?

Comment: How to find the closed form for the last derivative? Can you help?

Comment: For the problem of the derivatives, consider the Taylor expansion of $\frac{e^{-\sqrt{a}}}{\sqrt{a}$ around $a=1$. This is the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment*

Looking at your results and writing
$$I_n=\frac \pi {2e} a_n$$ we have the sequence
$$\left\{1,1,\frac{7}{8},\frac{37}{48},\frac{133}{192},\frac{2431}{3840},\frac{27007}{460
   80},\frac{176761}{322560},\frac{5329837}{10321920},\frac{12994393}{26542080}\right\}$$ the numerators correspond to sequence $A143991$ in $OEIS$. Taking into account what is the corresponding generating function
$$I_n=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi }}{2^n\,\Gamma (n)}\, K_{\frac{1}{2}-n}(1)$$ where appears  the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: The final result [has a name](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E11).

Comment: @metamorphy. I went to the same page. In Franch, we use to say "great minds think alike". This true excpet that I am not one of these. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4013056) of mine: $$I_{n+1}=\frac{\pi/e}{2n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2^{-n-k}(n+k)!}{k!(n-k)!}=\frac{\pi/e}{2^{2n+1}n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2^k(2n-k)!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$